# Issue with API bulk action using RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, rabbit-mq, bulk

I'm using RabbitMQ with Magento Community 2.3.1 version to handle Bulk REST API actions to update products.

That works fine.

But sometimes, with same messages, one item of the bulk action is not handled and the status of my bulk action stay in "Pending" because 2 messages were handled instead of 3 !

Do you have any idea of this issue?

Magento Community 2.3.1
RabbitMQ version : 3.7.9 Erlang 21.2.5

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

you can try to restart RabbitMQ service?

I configure like this https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-16-04-47
and it works